Since upgrading to Expo 52, I can't create any Stack Layout or Tabs. I always end up with this error

Warning: Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found 'Screen' for the screen 'index'). To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' prop to 'Screen'.

This is my layout Organisation
import { View, Text } from "@components/Themed";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import React from "react";

const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <View className="flex-1">
            <Stack
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false,
                }}
            >
                <Stack.Screen name="index" />
            </Stack>
        </View>
    );
};
export default Layout;

And the _layout.tsx and index.tsx are in the same directory.
I'm using "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.3", and "expo-router": "~4.0.6". This is using File-based Navigation Router.
I have tried updating @react-navigation/native, ran --expo prebuild.
I have tried a bunch of organisation tactics but none has worked. The moment I use a Stack or Tabs, the app crashes.

To be honest I have found it so much easier to use expo navigation with expo managed projects. Is that an option for you?
